# Nginx - allow HTTP for IP

Tags: http, nginx, https, ip

I have a configuration that will not allow any HTTP calls to my service (forcing https). I need to provide HTTP access to only one IP and I am not sure what is the best way to do that or if it's possible to do that with NGINX.

Here is my configuration:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name myserver.com;

        client_max_body_size 64M;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /com.key;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/log.log custom;

        if ($scheme = http) {
                return 400  "Sceme not allowed - please use https (SSL)";
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/my.sock:/;
                add_header Cache-Control private;
        }

        location /static/ {
                root /var/www/myapp/root;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have SSL enabled for port 80. You should use the `ssl` parameter on the `listen` directive and remove the `ssl on;` statement:

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
```

This allows non-SSL to port 80 and SSL to port 443.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do that, my service will accept all http requests. I would like to restrict http requests to one IP only. Is that possible ?

Comment: You should probably use two `server` blocks, one for each port.